# SQLite3 database or disk is full

Tags: sqlite

I am working on a linux server. When I submit the query like this one below,

```
create table test1 as select id, sum(amount) from sales group by id;
```

I got the error that "database or disk is full". I have contacted with the server administrator and he is sure that I have enough space for this query and he can generate this table without any problem.

Then I tried another query

```
create table test2 as select * from sales limit 100000000;
```

This time everything is good. My administrator believes that this is caused by permission problem. But I was wondering that if it is a permission problem, I could not generate table test2 at all. Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How many records? Have you configured temporary storage as memory or disk? Where? Do you have permissions there?

Comment: About 0.2 billion lines in sales table. Yes, the administrator has checked that and I have the permissions there and there are enough space too. I have ran even bigger queries without any problem before. It is very strange too me.

Comment: Try aliasing the `sum(amount)` column, as in `CREATE TABLE test1 AS SELECT id, SUM(amount) As SalesAmt FROM SALES GROUP BY ID;`.

Comment: I have tried aliasing, the same error popped up. It is just so frustrating.

Comment: `query like this one`.  Can you post your actual query? Maybe you're overlooking something when creating the analogous statement.

Comment: here it is, `create table test as select distinct file_date, sum(n_rating) as total_rating  from itunes_rating_daily group by file_date;`

Comment: Are you able to execute the query without the `create table ... as`?

Comment: `select ... ` gives me the same error.

Comment: Try COUNT and see how many entries you're actually dealing with.

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit SQLite?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your temporary directory is not full / is large enough: I've just hit this problem and it was caused by `/tmp` being completely full of junk. Wiping that out made it work fine.

Specifically in my instance:

`select 1 from table group by x`

was working, but

`select 1 from table group by x, y`

was not.

["Vacuum" command is failing with "SQL Error: Database or Disk is full"](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/quot-Vacuum-quot-command-is-failing-with-quot-SQL-Error-Database-or-disk-is-full-quot-td48238.html)